# Openshift - policy to keep pod logs after termination

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-pod, termination

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/support/troubleshooting/investigating-pod-issues.html

Says :

> Depending on policy and exit code, pod and container logs remain available after pods have been terminated.

But, doesn't say which policy can I set to make pod logs available after termination. Or which exit codes keep the logs. Anyone got any ideas? Clearly it must be possible to keep the logs available after termination, but how?

(Yes, I know I could probably use some external logging solution. But I don't have one handy and it'd be a lot of work to stand one up in the dev env and do whatever changes to make the pod being developed send it's logs there, all of which is not valid in "prod" environment so needs removing before changes can go live. Whereas a change to a policy somewhere is totally outside the code that launches the pod, so I can leave it in place in dev and not worry about making changes before dev work can go live.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't send pods to a external logging solution they'll be deleted after pod deletion or restart.

When a pod is deleted the logs are deleted with it, so if you perform an `oc delete pod <pod>` you can't retrieve them. Also if for some reason it has been deleted by the cluster itself, for example draining a node.

If you want to keep the logs of a failing pod you can change the [restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) to Never, so once one container fails the pod will be in `Error` state and you should be able to retrieve the logs.

In your case I guess you're trying to troubleshoot a failing pod that is restarting continuously?. If that's the case you could use the `-p` parameter so you can get the logs of the previous container execution:

`oc logs <pod> -c <container> -p`